# drupal 7 module for nodes with views

Tags: views, 7, panels, theming

I have a problem to find a right module in drupal to do something that should be simple.

I need my web content out into two columns. Entering a node should have title and description in the center column, and then a right column with related documents. It should be the same type of content.

In a previous work had solved with "views", the result:
http://www.imasmallorca.net/ca/unprograma/335

The problem to do with "views" it was not working the bread crumbs, nor the search. Neither the menu worked properly (not marked as an asset corresponding point)

Now, I'm working with "panels" to avoid this problem. It allows me to create columns, and embed a view with eg documents. The problem is that if I use a "panel page" does not appear in the search, and if I create a "panel node" I can pass arguments to the view in the right pane.

The question is: Is this right module? Should look for another module? is there another proper way to do this in Drupal?

Excuse my language, I'm Spanish :)

Thank you very much for your help, in another post I have been very useful.

Comment: So, basically you need a view as a field of a node?

Comment: i need to do something like this:
http://www.imasmallorca.net/es/area/10

Comment: This link does not help me to understand what you want. You ask for module to _____ nodes with views. But what's supposed to go in blank space, exactly? My understanding was in first comment, but I don't know if you wanted to agree or deny.

Answer (score 0):

Panels is the right module to control this kind of layout. You should be using the `node/%node` panel in Page Manager and be overriding that.
http://example.com/admin/structure/pages/nojs/operation/node_view/handlers/node_view_panel_context/content

The documents should be uploaded to the Node during editing. If you are missing a field for Documents create a Documents field in the node *Content Type* of *Field Type* **file**. Allow it to have infinite values.

Return to [Page Manager > Content](http://example.com/admin/structure/pages/nojs/operation/node_view/handlers/node_view_panel_context/content). Add content into the right hand panel (using the gear icon). Choose Node and locate your **Field: Documents**. Add that.

Add your other content into the centre panel. Your left hand panel can be a block (for example a **Menus** block).

Comment: very well explained, helpful reply